# NGramTokenizer - source code of port

Tags: lucene.net

I am trying to find the source code for the NGramTokenizer - Lucene.Net (C#). Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

2.9.2 doesn't look to have that feature yet. But the work-in-progress trunk looks to have it:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/contrib/Analyzers/NGram/NGramTokenizer.cs